# What's the difference between "expression <=1." and "expression <= 1"?

Tags: sql-server

Reviewing code and a case statement has `expression <= 1.` as opposed to `<= 1`

I'm not sure what the purpose of the `1.` is.  Any thoughts?

Comment: SQL Server treats the `1.` literal as numeric(1,0) instead of integer due to the period.  Perhaps that was specified in order to match the data type of the expression (a best practice).  Personally, I'd specify `1.0` in that case.

Comment: The lack of any `0` after the decimal point and the fact that `decimal` has higher datatype precedence than `int` so the constant would be implicitly cast anyway if needed would make me think that it is likely a typing error rather than deliberate.

Answer (score 18):

`1.` is a `NUMERIC` (or `DECIMAL`) constant, while `1` is an `INTEGER` constant. In some cases it is useful to specify the data type of a constant explicitly to avoid an unnecessary (or undesirable) implicit type conversion.

Consider, for example

```
create table t(f1 int);
insert into t values (2);
```

Then `select 1/f1 from t` returns `0` (`INTEGER`), while `select 1./f1 from t` returns `0.5` (`DECIMAL`).

One might assume that on the left side of the comparison in your example there is a `DECIMAL` column, and explicitly specifying a `DECIMAL` constant could marginally improve performance by avoiding an implicit type cast.